# Can VS Code debugging use sourceMapPathOverrides along with serverReadyAction / debugWithChrome?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When debugging web app server code in VS Code (.NET Core in my case), there is a `launch.json` configuration option called `serverReadyAction` to open the web browser, e.g.:

```
"serverReadyAction": {
    "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"   ,
    "action": "openExternally"
}
```

`openExternally` is one possible action, and `debugWithChrome` is another. The latter starts a Chrome debug session using the Debugger for Chrome extension. In this mode, a `webRoot` property can be added that is passed to the Chrome debug session:

```
"serverReadyAction": {
    "action": "debugWithChrome",
    "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"   ,
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/wwwroot"
}
```

The nice thing about this is that now I can hit breakpoints in my C# *and* my client-side JavaScript - lovely!

However, my JS is actually compiled from TypeScript and bundled (with Webpack in this case). Ordinarily when using the Debugger for Chrome extension, I can tell it about `sourceMapPathOverrides`. A typical config would be:

```
{
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "url": "https://localhost:5001",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
    "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
    }
}
```

My question is if this is possible when using the a Chrome debug session created by `serverReadyAction` / `debugWithChrome`. It's not immediately apparent.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to pass this option in, but I did see that the Chrome debugger extension has default properties for it:

```
 "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "type": "object",
                "description": "%chrome.sourceMapPathOverrides.description%",
                "default": {
                  "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*",
                  "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                  "webpack:///*": "*",
                  "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",
                  "meteor://app/*": "${webRoot}/*"
                }
              },
```

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/blob/3771e9343c0776be19db6ba4653a7e4e7fdb96a6/package.json

So I can debug my TypeScript so long as my project files match one of those.